# Detecting CPU capabilities at compile time and "dispatching" on them

Tags: julia, llvm

Is it possible to write a function which would use different algorithms depending on Julia/LLVM compile target?

The goal is to do this at compile-time, and hopefully to make this function inline-able.

Just to have some code, this could look like:

```
function do_it()
    if (CPU_has_avx512) # resolved at compile. code for one branch generated
        ...
    else
        ...
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the following macro:

```
using CpuId
macro cpuf(what)
    quote
        $(CpuId.cpufeature(what.value))
    end
end
```

This obviously replaces a call with a fixed value at compile time:

```
julia> @macroexpand @cpuf(:AVX)
quote
    #= REPL[75]:3 =#
    true
end
```

So now we can dispatch on the `Val` type:

```
f1(::Val{true}) = 100
f1(::Val{false}) = -100
```

```
julia> f1(Val{@cpuf(:AVX)}())
100
```

And this all gets compiled-in as you wanted:

```
julia> @code_llvm f1(Val{@cpuf(:AVX)}())
;  @ REPL[89]:1 within `f1`
; Function Attrs: uwtable
define i64 @julia_f1_935() #0 {
top:
  ret i64 100
}
```

Comment: Looking good! Thanks. I'll let everyone who wants chime in do it and then mark it. Does the `cpuefeature` function need to be defined somehow special to constant propagate like this? And one last question, is there anywhere this type of machine-dependant calculation is used in the eco-system right now?

Comment: `$` inside of the `code` block makes this code to be executed at the compile time. I believe this can be any Julia code and such code will be executed during compilation (of course in some corner scenarios maybe we could have world age issues etc). So the `cpufeature` is not special in any way. Regarding where the machine dependent calculation  is used now - I do not know. I would suspect that interesting with this regard could be happening around the libblastrampoline project. Basically, in most cases people want to have replicable experiments in science rather than platform dependent code.

Comment: "_people want to have replicable experiments_ " for sure, but LLVM is platform dependent (but hopefully quite replicable across platforms). The question regards cases when you want to optimize manually an algorithm to a platform beyond LLVM low-level optimization.

Comment: so with my code you can do exactly that! I agree that trying to guess what people want is even more platform dependent ;)

Answer (score 1):

In a similar manner to @Przemyslaw Szufel's answer, you can use [`@static`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@static) macro to partially evaluate an expression at parse-time to achieve what you want.

```
julia>function f()
          @static if Sys.ARCH === :aarch64
              return -1
          else
              return +1
          end
      end

julia> @code_llvm f()
;  @ REPL[10]:1 within `f`
define i64 @julia_f_515() #0 {
top:
  ret i64 -1
}
```

You can see the same structure being used by Julia itself [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/199cac7d1d474d6bf512943fb6485a53e574e8eb/base/math.jl#L894).

You can checkout [`CpuId.jl`](https://github.com/m-j-w/CpuId.jl) package to query CPU features as suggested by @Przemyslaw Szufel's answer.

Comment: Oh this looks like a good alternative, and even closer to the code scaffold in the question. Any reason this would be better/different than other solution?

Comment: Writing a macro yourself is more powerful (code can do more things). The solution by @hckr seems to be sufficient for your needs.